# How to display the selected rows of the grid view in another form using C# Form application?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want display data from `DataGridView` in second form to text boxes in the first form, when i selected row with double click event .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FRM_DRIVERS_LIST frm = new FRM_DRIVERS_LIST();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            this.txt_code.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_Driver_Name.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_Tel1.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_Tel2.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            this.txt_Address.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            this.dtp_S_work.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            this.CB_WorkPlace.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            this.CB_License_type.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            this.dTP_Date_e_License.Text = frm.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            txt_code.ReadOnly = true;
            btn_Edite.Enabled = true;
            btn_Delete.Enabled = true;
            btn_Add.Enabled = false;
        }
```

this is second form code that have `DataGridView` :-

```
public partial class FRM_DRIVERS_LIST : Form
    {
        BL.CLS_DRIVERS clsDriver = new BL.CLS_DRIVERS();

        int ID;

        public FRM_DRIVERS_LIST()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dGV_Driver.DataSource = clsDriver.GET_ALL_DRIVERS();
            dGV_Driver.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }


        private void txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = clsDriver.Search_Driver(txt_Search.Text);
            this.dGV_Driver.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void dGV_Driver_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //FRM_DRIVERS frm = new FRM_DRIVERS();
            //ID = Convert.ToInt32(this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            //frm.txt_code.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //frm.txt_Driver_Name.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            //frm.txt_Tel1.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            //frm.txt_Tel2.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            //frm.txt_Address.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            //frm.dtp_S_work.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            //frm.CB_WorkPlace.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            //frm.CB_License_type.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            //frm.dTP_Date_e_License.Text = this.dGV_Driver.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            this.Close();
        }
```

This code is work but i have problem , when i close second form the first row is display in the text box in first form i want display only when i double click on the row

Comment: please add code, whatever you have done till now.

Comment: Please re-visit [ask] and use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

```
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
            frm3.textBox7.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            frm3.textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            frm3.textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            frm3.textBox9.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            frm3.dateTimePicker1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            frm3.textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            frm3.textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
```

to display only particular cell in particular textbox on different form...this would help

Answer (score -1):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx

```
 DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
      Form2 frm = new Form2(row);
      frm.Show();
```

hope this helps.